# Change progress bar max value with integer

Tags: android

In my Timer app there is a progress bar to set the time for the countdown. I managed it to make the progress bar move with the progress of the countdown, but now I want to make this: Whenever I start the Countdown, the Progress Bar max should be set to the value of the timer integer. So e.g. if I set my countdown to 30s and start it, my progress bar should jump to the right and show me the progress from all right to left. Similar the circle on Samsungs standart clock app countdown. How do I manage that? I hope you understand what I mean.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SeekBar timerSeekbar;
    TextView timertextview;
    boolean counteractiv = false;
    Button gobutton;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    int progress;

    public void resetTimer(){

        countDownTimer.cancel();
        timertextview.setText("0:30");
        timerSeekbar.setEnabled(true);
        counteractiv = false;
        gobutton.setText("Start");
        timerSeekbar.setMax(600);
        timerSeekbar.setProgress(30);

    }

    public void buttonclicked(View view){

        if(counteractiv){
            resetTimer();
        }else{
            //timerSeekbar.setMax((int)secondsleft);
            counteractiv = true;
            timerSeekbar.setEnabled(false);
            gobutton.setText("Stop!");

            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timerSeekbar.getProgress() * 1000, 1000){

                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {
                    updatetimer((int)l/1000);

                    timerSeekbar.setProgress((int)l/1000);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time over!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    gobutton.setText("Reset");
                }
            }.start();

            timerSeekbar.setMax((int)progress/1000);
        }

    }

    public void updatetimer(int secondsleft){

        int minutes = secondsleft/60;
        int seconds = secondsleft - (minutes*60);

        String secondsString = Integer.toString(seconds);
        String minutesString = Integer.toString(minutes);

        if(seconds <=9){
            secondsString = "0" + secondsString;
        }

        timertextview.setText(minutesString + ":" + secondsString);
        timerSeekbar.setProgress(secondsleft);

        progress = secondsleft;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timerSeekbar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        timertextview = findViewById(R.id.CountdowntextView);
        gobutton = findViewById(R.id.StartButton);

        timerSeekbar.setMax(600);
        timerSeekbar.setProgress(30);

        timerSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                updatetimer(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

So basically I've tried to cast the progress of the bar into the global integer `progress` and use this to define `timerSeekbar.setMax((int)progress)`
But where do I set place this line of code to make it work properly?

Comment: what's wrong with updating the progress bar in onTick()?

Comment: Well, updating the current status of the bar works there, but not `timerSeekbar.setMax((int)progress)`. Bc it would reset the max every tick and that's not what I want

Comment: you want to keep the seekbar at max position when you reset it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it works. You have to set the setProgress to your max when reseting. Here timertextview and seekbarmax should be matching for getting proper result. Also the CountDownTimer constructor should be like below example.

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SeekBar timerSeekbar;
    TextView timertextview;
    boolean counteractiv = false;
    Button gobutton;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    int progress;

    public void resetTimer() {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        timertextview.setText("0:30");
        timerSeekbar.setEnabled(true);
        counteractiv = false;
        gobutton.setText("Start");
        timerSeekbar.setMax(30);
        timerSeekbar.setProgress(30);
    }

    public void buttonclicked(View view) {

        if (counteractiv) {
            resetTimer();
        } else {
            //timerSeekbar.setMax((int)secondsleft);
            counteractiv = true;
            // timerSeekbar.setEnabled(false);
            gobutton.setText("Stop!");
            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30 * 1000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {
                    updatetimer((int) l / 1000);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Toast.makeText(EthopiaActivity.this, "Time over!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    gobutton.setText("Reset");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }

    public void updatetimer(int secondsleft) {

        int minutes = secondsleft / 60;
        int seconds = secondsleft - (minutes * 60);

        String secondsString = Integer.toString(seconds);
        String minutesString = Integer.toString(minutes);

        if (seconds <= 9) {
            secondsString = "0" + secondsString;
        }

        timertextview.setText(minutesString + ":" + secondsString);
        timerSeekbar.setProgress(secondsleft);
        progress = secondsleft;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        timerSeekbar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        timertextview = findViewById(R.id.CountdowntextView);
        gobutton = findViewById(R.id.StartButton);
        timerSeekbar.setMax(30);
        timerSeekbar.setProgress(1);

        timerSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                updatetimer(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

xml would look like this, here you must remove the static values (max and progress)

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />
```

good luck.